# C++ getline is not empty when no input is entered

Tags: c++, cin, getline, istream

I am new to c++ and still trying to wrap my head around how input/output streams work.

I am currently trying to write a function to make sure the user enters an int, and tell them if the input is empty or not a valid int.

I am using getline and have tried using cin.clear and cin.ignore but i cannot seem to get this to work and have no idea where i am going wrong.

It works if I input a letter however if i just press enter with nothing input it doesn't say no input detected.

```
void testStuff()
{
    string number;

    ws(cin);//skips Whitespaces

    if (getline(cin, number) && number.end() !=
        find_if_not(number.begin(), number.end(), &isdigit))
    {
        if (number.empty())
        {
            cout << "No input detected" << endl;
            testStuff();
        }
        cout << "Please input a Valid number" << endl;
        testStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the string is empty the only thing `find_if_not` can return is `number.end()`. `number.end() == number.end()` and body is not entered.

Comment: Assuming your `ws` works as specified, you shouldn't be able to enter an empty input. If you just press the `enter` key, that will be read as a new-line character, which is classified as white-space (i.e., `isspace('\n') == true`). For `getline` to be called, you have to enter something that's not whitespace, so what you read with `getline` can't be empty.

Comment: @JerryCoffin yes but the ws comes before the getline call

Comment: @user4581301 I see what you are saying, I should check if its empty first

Comment: @MichaelGrinnell: Precisely--so for execution to proceed to calling `getline`, the user has to enter something that's not white-space. When getline is called, that non-whitespace character has to be in the input buffer, so what it reads can't possibly be empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `ws` works as specified (skips whitespace in the input), by the time you call `getline`, something other than whitespace has to have been entered. Thus, when `getline` gets called, that non-whitespace character has to be waiting in the input buffer, and `getline` must return a non-empty sequence of characters (i.e., everything from that first non-whitespace character up to the next new-line).

For example, let's write our own `ws` that shows what character(s) it's skipping over:

```
void ws(std::istream &is) {
    while (std::isspace(is.peek())) {
        char ch;
        is.get(ch);
        std::cout << "Read: " << (int)ch << '\n';
    }
}
```

Now, when we call `testStuff()` and just press <kbd>enter</kbd>, we get `Read: 10` as our output--i.e., `ws` has read and skipped the new-line we entered.

So, to get to the call to `getline`, the user *has* to enter something other than whitespace, and a new-line is whitespace. So, but the time `getline` is called at all, we know there's some non-whitespace character waiting in the input buffer, so when `getline` is called, it *must* produce a non-empty result.

Comment: Ok right, yes that took me a minute to wrap my head around. Basically get rid of the ws, check if input is empty first then check if its a digit. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed that every of function(s) that i don't know implementation are written correctly. Then, I have such code (simplified):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string number;
    if (getline(cin, number))
    {
        if (number.empty())
        {
            cout << "No input detected" << endl;
            main();
        }
        cout << "Please input a Valid number" << endl;
        main();
    }
}
```

I don't know `find_if_not(number.begin(), number.end(), &isdigit)` implementation so I skipped it. I've put source code on Ideone.com, you can view it [HERE](https://ideone.com/4687Jm). After passing "just enter", program behaves vaildly. This means, one of function implementations that you didn't show us is working incorrectly. To help you we need full source code (if not, just only needed parts). Also, you should skip "using namespace std;". I think, `number.end() != find_if_not(number.begin(), number.end(), &isdigit))` is implemented incorrectly. You should think about what someone told you in comments - "If the string is empty the only thing find_if_not can return is number.end(). number.end() == number.end() and body is not entered."

Comment: Calling `main` from within a program is bad.

Comment: Ofcourse is, but it's quick and dirty example. I dont want to make 60-line program just to make it "vaild", while such program behaves as it should. I don't think OP will use my code...

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk find_if_not takes in the first and last position and returns an iterator to the first occurrence of a specific condition. So isdigit is the condition so if it returns the last element it means there are no integers